# How to calculate the inverse of the line integral.

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, inverse

Let $f$ be a polynomial function,
$$ f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + ... + a_d x^d $$
where $a_0$, $a_1$, ..., $a_d$ are parameters and usually $d \le 6$.

Let $g$ be the line integral of $f$, 
$$ g(x) = \int_0^x \sqrt{1 + f'(x)^2}dx $$

Now I want to know $g^{-1}(y)$, where $y$ = $1, 2, ..., m$.

Do you have any suggestions on how I should calculate it?

Notice: The answer is not necessary close-formed, it is ok as long as fast and accurate.

Answer (score 1):

An intuitive answer:

(1)set g=0,x=0,m=0;

(2)choose a step size h and do the numerical integral from x to x+h. Take Simpsion Scheme for example
$$
g=g+\frac{(F(x)+4F(x+\frac{h}{2})+F(x+h))}{6}h
$$
and set x=x+h; here $F(x)=\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}$;

(3) If g>m, we have $g^{-1}(m)=x$ and set m=m+1;

Repeat (2)(3) until we find all the results.

I have to admit this is a naive answer since I didn't take the special form of F(x) into consideration. But this method could work fast and accurate as long as you choose a proper step size h in (2).